# Help! I've put Don't starve in fullscreen and then minimized it, now I can't un-minimize it

Tags: dont-starve

I've started up Don't starve and went into the settings and made it fullscreen, but that minimized it. I tried deleting local game files and then re-installing it but that still won't fix it.

Comment: Games often do this if you have their settings set to run an a resolution your computer doesn't support.  Check the resolution setting and see if it is something you can set your monitor to.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your `settings.ini` file.  You can find it in your user directory.  For instance, mine is at:

> C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Klei\DoNotStarve\settings.ini

If you can't find any settings there to fix the minimization, you might try just deleting the settings.ini file to see if the game will re-create it.  (Don't permanently delete it; just send it to the Recycle Bin, so you can get it back if this experiment doesn't work.)